# Find image tag in my html page and replace with a domain name using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have many images on my html page which looks like below...

```
<img src="/v/photos/80137-1.jpg" border=0 alt=""></a>
  <img src="myimage.jpg" border=0 alt=""></a>
```

so what i need to do is find all the < img tag in a page > and on body load replace it with

```
<img src="http://www.abc.com/v/photos/80137-1.jpg" border=0 alt=""></a>
<img src="http://www.abc.com/myimage.jpg" border=0 alt=""></a>
```

So i am wondering if there is a way to do it using Jquery?

Comment: Why? Just use `<base href="http://www.abc.com" />` (or whatever it is), surely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do:

```
$(function() {
    $('img').each(function(){
       this.src = "http://www.abc.com/"+$(this).attr('src');
    });
});
```

EDIT - just to explain why i used this.src on the left and `$(this).attr('src')` on the right:

`this.src` is faster to access than it's jQuery counterpart, but on the right returns the full path to the image, so if i put this example in jsFiddle `this.src` returns `http://jsfiddle.net/myimage.jpg` while `$(this).attr('src')` returns only what's written in the `src` attribute: `myimage.jpg`.

Look at this fiddle if this is not clear: http://jsfiddle.net/6cHxR/9/

EDIT 2 - use the final `/` in the url you are adding (that means use `http://www.abc.com/`). In this way links will work both if their `src` begins with `/` and if it doesn't

Comment: Efficient? `$(this).attr('src')` instead of `this.src`. You probably want a `/`, too.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal i tried this in jsfiddle and using this.src returned  `http://jsfiddle.net/myimage.jpg` so i used `attr()`. Of course this.src is more efficient and in fact i used it on the left  side

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: Indeed, it surprised me that you used it on the LHS but not the RHS. But it seems you have a reason (which I'd have written into the answer, but there we go!). I'd still suggest the `/`, though.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal look here http://jsfiddle.net/6cHxR/9/ I think that this.src is the "evalued" value, so in this case i just need the part that is in the attribute

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal i took the `/` away because in the first image the `src` already had it..it depends how you write links in the `src`

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: Yes, it does; if you write `/` and the `src` already has it then there's no harm. If the `src` doesn't then it'll work, whereas without it it won't.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal good point, i added it to my answer, thank you

Comment: I tried using the following but its not showing the image, offcourse i change domain name to real one and the image exists

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('img').each(function(){
   this.src = "http://abc.com"+$(this).attr('src');
});
</head>


<body id="body" >
<img src="/v/photos/80137-1.jpg" border=0 alt=""></a> 
</body>
</html>

Comment: @user580950 there must be some other problem because with an existing image it works, look here http://jsfiddle.net/6cHxR/10/ (maybe try to make a fiddle that points to your images)

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti  I checked it at http://jsfiddle.net/6cHxR/9/ but it seems that First alert is Good but second and third alert doesnt looks right its adding double urls.. ?

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti Here is my html page http://tinyurl.com/d7flr5g its not showing the image though image exists at http://tinyurl.com/cm5p4aq

Comment: @user580950 the image in your second url is not showing (in fact there is no image here http://dev10.edisbest.com/v/vspfiles/photos/80137-1.jpg)